# Migration and Error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, migration, propel

The site directory was moved to a different server and now I'm getting this error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Apache Server at www.samplesite.com Port 80

I've tried changing the paths from

`/www/sites/samplesite.com` to
 `/var/www/www.samplesite.com` on the config and settings files but the same error is showing. How do I determine what the problem could be? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

do you have access administrator on server?
if you have, try the commands bellow:

```
$ chmod 755 /var/www/
```

or change user/group owner:

```
$ chown -R wwwuser:wwwgroup /var/www/
```

Obs.: change wwwuser and wwwgroup with the user and group default of http server configuration.

Comment: verify directive DocumentRoot in your apache file configuration